# How to implement feature Extraction algorithm for handwritten signature comparison in java?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I want to compare two handwritten signature(scanned images of signature) in java.I Found Feature extraction algorithm for offline signature verification.Same algorithm i want to implement in java.

Any one can help on this?